# Handle nested object with Logstah and XPath

Tags: elasticsearch, xpath, logstash

I have an XML structure

```
<Event>
  <Core Id="10233" />
  <Parameters>
      <Parameter EngValue="1.0" DecValue="1.0" />
      <Parameter EngValue="GCOM" />
      <Parameter EngValue="1.0" DecValue="1.0" />
  </Parameters>
</Event>
```

I’d like Logstash to output this structure :

```
{
  "CoreID" : "10233",
  "Parameter" : [
    {
      "EngValue" : "1.0",
      "DecValue" : "1.0"
    },
    {
      "EngValue" : "GCOM"
    },
    {
      "EngValue" : "1.0",
      "DecValue" : "1.0"
    }
  ]
}
```

With the XML filter I tried :

```
xpath => [
    "/Event/Core/@Id", "CoreID",
    "/Event/Parameters/Parameter/@DecValue", "[Parameter][DecValue]",
    "/Event/Parameters/Parameter/@EngValue", "[Parameter][EngValue]",
]
```

But so far I only got this :

```
{
  "CoreID" : "10233",
  "Parameter" : {
      "EngValue" : ["1.0", "GCOM", "1.0"],
      "DecValue" : ["1.0", "1.0"]
    }
}
```

How can I make “Parameter” the array instead of its attributes?

I tried to use a Ruby filter to create the "Parameter" object. But right after the XML filter (i.e when my Ruby filter begins) I have to "join" the arrays `"EngValue" : ["1.0", "GCOM", "1.0"]` and `"DecValue" : ["1.0", "1.0"]`.

The problem is that for each element of “EngValue”, I don’t know the corresponding element in “DecValue”.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't mind using ruby, I'd suggest something like this:

```
filter {
  xml {
    source => "message"
    target => "parsed"
  }

  ruby {
      code => '
        event.set("Parameter", event.get("[parsed][Parameters][0][Parameter]"))
        event.set("CoreId", event.get("[parsed][Core][0][Id]"))
      '
  }


  mutate {
    remove_field => ["message", "parsed"]
  }
}
```

Which should output:

```
{
    "@timestamp" => 2017-08-29T13:45:46.112Z,
      "@version" => "1",
          "host" => "my-host",
     "Parameter" => [
        [0] {
            "DecValue" => "1.0",
            "EngValue" => "1.0"
        },
        [1] {
            "EngValue" => "GCOM"
        },
        [2] {
            "DecValue" => "1.0",
            "EngValue" => "1.0"
        }
    ],
        "CoreId" => "10233"
}
```